# Refer to argument in condition for other argument

Tags: argument-patterns

The condition for `b` here doesn't recognize `a`. How can I fix this?

```
f[a_Integer, b_Integer /; Divisible[a, b]] := a/b
f[6,2]
(* f[6,2] *)
a = 4;
f[6,2]
(* 3 *)
```

Comment: Put the condition outside the function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@user5601 and your analysis explain the problem and the solution

```
g[a_Integer, b_Integer] /; Divisible[a, b] := a/b
g[6, 2]
(* 3 *)
```

You attached the condition to the pattern `b_Integer` so you were testing against the global `a` not the local `a`.

(In my version) Mathematica highlights `b` in your original condition, but not `a`, so  this points to the problem.